# Updating fields in array -NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code that loop through all users in DB then look for specific `events` based on the `id` value and if there is a match it should update the field `caption` with a new given data,

for the code :

1-  search all potential user = OK

2 - search and find events based on `id` = OK

3- update the field `caption` = NOK

this is my code hope I mentioned everything

```
router.post('/delete/:id',async (req, res) => {
 const eventId = req.params.id // this is the ID of the event
  User.find({}).lean(true).exec((err, users) => {
    let getTEvent = [];


    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      if (users[i].events && users[i].events.length) {

        for (let j = 0; j < users[i].events.length; j++) {
          if (users[i].events[j]._id === eventId) { 
            console.log('you event is :'+ eventId)  // this statement to verify if really got the correct ID or not
            users[i].events[j].caption ="deleted" // from here the problem
            users[i].save(err => {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log("status changed saved");
              // Redirect back after the job is done.

            });

          }
        }
      }
    }


  });
  })
```

the error that I get is that `users[i].save is not a function` I don't know with what should I replace it,

As per comments @whoami

```
router.post('/delete/:id', (req, res) =>
  User.findOneAndUpdate({
    "events._id": req.params.id
    },
    { $set: { "events.caption": "yesssss" }
  }, {upsert: true}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send('error updating ');
    } else {
      console.log(user);
      console.log(req.params.id)
  }
}));
```

Below the mongoDb and event datastructure

[image]
[image]

Hope I clarified everything ,

Best Regards,

Comment: `.save()` works on mongoose document but not on javaScript object, In your code you've already converted mongoose documents returned from find call to .Js objects using : `.lean(true)` !! You can use `.findOneAndUpdate()` with a unique filter to find particular user document & update entire `events` array. Or **more simple** instead of reading all docs & iterating in code (Which is not preferred at all) you can take advantage of same `.findOneAndUpate()` to update docs in just one DB call..

Comment: Please edit this question with sample docs + input + conditions & required o/p, for a better way to do this..

Comment: @whoami thank you for your answer do you mean I update this question with what you mention in comments above?

Comment: I recommend to do so, cause you don't need to do all the things what you're doing right now just to update a field inside an array object..!!

Comment: Yeah I 'm so blind I'm doing it the Hard way i will try to modify and see results

Comment: @whoami could it be possible to take a look the question above I updated it , any help is appreciated :D

Comment: Please edit this question with sample docs or Does your user document look like this `{name :'someUserName', events : [{_id :123, caption : 'something'}, {_id :456, caption : 'something2'}]}` ?

Comment: @whoami I updated the question with DB structure for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actual Issue :**

`.save()` works on mongoose document but not on javaScript object. In your code you've already converted mongoose documents returned from `.find()` call to .Js objects using : `.lean(true)`.

`.lean(true)` is used to convert mongoose docs to .Js objects to work manipulate fields inside docs in code.

**Fixing code :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

router.post("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const eventId = req.params.id; // this is the ID of the event
  await User.find({})
    .lean(true)
    .exec((err, users) => {
      let getTEvent = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (users[i].events && users[i].events.length) {
          for (let j = 0; j < users[i].events.length; j++) {
            if (users[i].events[j]._id === eventId) {
              console.log("you event is :" + eventId);
              users[i].events[j].caption = "deleted";
              users[i]._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(users[i]._id); // Converting `_id` string to `ObjectId()` to match with type of `_id` in DB
              let user = new User(users[i]); // Create a mongoose doc out of model
              user.save((err) => { // As we're passing `_id` in doc to `.save()` it will be an update call rather-than insert
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("status changed saved");
                // Redirect back after the job is done.
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
});
```

As I've mentioned this can be done with out this extra process of reading docs/iteration/update call. Using `.updateOne()` or `.updateMany()` along with [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) positional operator things can be done in one DB call :

```
 const mongoose = require('mongoose');
router.post("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const eventId = req.params.id; // this is the ID of the event
  /** We're using `.updateMany` with filter on `events._id` - 
   * So that all user docs which has `'events._id': eventId` will be updated,
   * If you've a particular user needs to be updated used `.updateOne()` with a filter to find that user document - filter kind of `userName` 
   * 
   * Both `.updateMany()` or `.update()` will return write result but not the docs,
   * if you need docs in response use `.findOneAndUpdate` or `.findAndModify()`
   */

   /** `$` helps to update particular object's caption field in `events` array (Object where `{ 'events._id': eventId }` ) */

   await User.updateMany({ 'events._id': eventId },{$set : {'events.$.caption': 'deleted'}}).exec((err)=>{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("status changed saved");
    // Redirect back after the job is done.
  })
});
```

**Ref :** [update-documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/index.html)